# How to change text colour of single cell in Kable Extra?

Tags: r, kableextra

Is there a way of changing the text colour of a single cell/multiple cells?

For example, I have a table that I changed the colour of all text to red.
But I want the diagonal colour to be blue

Is there a way to achieve this?

I have tried to use `testStats[1, 2] <- cell_spec(testStats[1, 2], "latex", color = "blue")` to change colour for one cell.

But doesn't seem to work.

```r
library(kaleExtra)

test = iris
testStats = as.data.frame(apply(iris[,1:4], 2, summary))

kable(testStats, booktabs =TRUE,caption = "Sample") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c('hold_position')) %>%
  column_spec(2:5, color = "red")


  testStats[1, 2] <- cell_spec(testStats[1, 2], "latex", color = "blue")
```

Comment: Need a [MCVE]. Include needed `library` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cell_spec` in a loop to change multiple cells. For diagonals you can do -

```
library(kableExtra)

test = iris
testStats = as.data.frame(round(apply(iris[,1:4], 2, summary), 2))
for(i in seq_along(testStats)) {
  testStats[i, i] <- cell_spec(testStats[i, i], "html", color = "blue")
}

kable(testStats, 'html', booktabs =TRUE,caption = "Sample", escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c('hold_position')) %>%
  column_spec(2:5, color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. However, this doesn't seem to work when I knit it into pdf. I also try changing the line in for loop into ```testStats[i, i] <- cell_spec(testStats[i, i], "latex", color = "blue")``` But when I knit into pdf, it will shows up as \textcolor{blue}{0} in red. Is there anyway to achieve this in pdf?